# Firehose - JSON attribute on S3 prefix

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm setting up a Firehose that will delivery JSON messages to a bucket S3. The setup was pretty easy and it's working but I would like to add a prefix on S3 like `<event>/YYYY/MM/DD/HH`.

I'm reading the docs but i didn't found a way to get an attribute value from my json and use it on prefix. I would like to use a custom prefix to split my events type.

Is possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each delivery stream can be configured to have only a single prefix (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-deliver.html#s3-object-name):

```
"S3Configuration": { 
     "BucketARN": "string",
     "BufferingHints": { 
        "IntervalInSeconds": number,
        "SizeInMBs": number
     },
     "CloudWatchLoggingOptions": { 
        "Enabled": boolean,
        "LogGroupName": "string",
        "LogStreamName": "string"
     },
     "CompressionFormat": "string",
     "EncryptionConfiguration": { 
        "KMSEncryptionConfig": { 
           "AWSKMSKeyARN": "string"
        },
        "NoEncryptionConfig": "string"
     },
     "Prefix": "string",
     "RoleARN": "string"
  }
```

A possible workaround can be to filter events in your application code and send them to a correct delivery stream.